# How do isolated conductor store energy?

Tags: capacitance

> Capacitance is the ability to store electrical energy

An isolated spherical conducter also posses capcitance.But how?How can it store energy?

Usually capcitors have a pair of opposite charges,like[image]

But an **isolated** charged conductor does not have any other charge nearby.How can it store energy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can think of the other electrode as being infinity of the Earth or some other object.

If you "isolated" spherical conductor is uncharged the to charge it you must take charge from somewhere and place it on the conductor.

When you find the capacitance of concentric sphere of radius $b$ and $a$ with $b>a$, $C = 4 \pi \epsilon_o \left ( \dfrac {ab}{b-a}\right)$ and then allow $b \rightarrow \infty$, ie make the other plate go to infinity, you get the caopacitance of an isolated sphere $C = 4 \pi \epsilon_o a$.